# Dt acting on symbolic notational forms

Tags: syntax

This one must be simple, but I can't figure out a decent solution.

Suppose, I have a symbol with a notational form applied to it, say `OverHat[A]`.
Now, if I didn't specify anything about `A`, I would expect `Dt[OverHat[A]]` staying unevaluated.

But in reality `OverHat` gets evaluated:
`Dt[OverHat[A]] (* --->  Dt[A] Derivative[1][OverHat][A] *)`

What are possible ways to prevent this from happening?

**EDIT**

To state more clearly, I want `OverHat[A]` to behave like ordinary symbol under action of `Dt`:

`Dt[symb] (* --->  Dt[symb] *)`

Comment: ...but you are differentiating with respect to what? Anyway, have a look at the `Constants` option of `Dt[]`.

Comment: @J. M., `Dt[OverHat[A]]` is a total differential of `OverHat[A]` in my case. Setting `A` (or even `OverHat`) to a constant doesn't work, it just gives zero.

Comment: @SaF You mean `HoldForm@Dt[OverHat[A]]` ? (BTW, setting A to a constant of course cause 0, since Dt[A]=0 in this case.)

Comment: @luyuwuli, `HoldForm` is a possible workaround, but this way the head of my expression will be `HoldForm`, which is unwanted. I want `OverHat[A]` to be treated like an ordinary unspecified symbol by `Dt`, e.g. `Dt[OverHat[A]]=Dt[OverHat[A]]`

Comment: How about using a new symbol like `overA` in place of OverHat[A]? The problem is that `OverHat` is a typesetting function (like `MatrixForm` or `Subscript`) and you're trying to make it do something it isn't intended to do.

Comment: @bill s, That's what I did in the end :) But after completing my calculations I want to TeXForm results and paste them in LaTeX, and I found it too dreary to replace all my variables like `overA` to `OverHat[A]` manually. P.S. Isn't "trying to make it do something it isn't intended to do" the most beautiful part of Mathematica? :)

Comment: Well then, how about: `text//.overA->OverHat[A]` ?

Comment: @bill s, I've tried and it doesn't work correctly, because we end up with the same thing, `Dt[OverHat[A]]`.

Comment: I mean after all the computations are done... this is just for show/display, right? You don't need to "replace all the variables by hand" as in your comment, you can do the replacement automatically *after* the computations are finished.

Comment: @bills, Could you please elaborate on your answer? Consider this simple example: `result=TeXForm[Dt[ovA]+Dt[ohB]]`, then applying `result //. {ovA -> OverVector[A], ohB -> OverHat[B]}` gives me $dA \text{OverVector}'(A)+dB \text{OverHat}'(B)$

Comment: I see the issue... I have always copied and pasted the output of TexForm into a latex editor, and that makes it appear as if it were plain text. But now I see it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official way of solving such notational problems is to use the following package:

```
Needs["Notation`"]

Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
OverscriptBox["A", "^"]]]
```

Now you can enter the notation in the usual way to get this:

[image: screen shot]

You have to do this for every hat-symbol individually, though.